# PHP - change object props by prop name

Tags: php, oop, stdclass

I've got some array of propeties to change on some objects and values to apply in such format:

```
$toApply = array(
    "post.author.status.time" => 0,
    "page.title" => "My title",
    "page.tags" => "My, Tags"
)
```

And I've got objects `$post` and `$page` that are stdClass objects so I can easly write code like `$page->title = "My title"`

I'm also aware that I can do it by

```
$prop = "title";
$page->{$prop} = "My title"
```

**However it works only on 1 level objects.**

The problem is how to go deeply inside object (also creating needed sub-propeties if needed if object for example has no propeties yet and I've got `"page.someprop.deeperprop.deepprop.title"`)

My 1-level function looks like:

```
function applyProp($prop, $value, $obj) {
    $forSureObj = (object) $obj;

    $forSureObj->{$prop} = $value;
    return $forSureObj;
}
```

Comment: `$obj->{$lvl1}->{$lvl2}` etc ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I know it, but how to do it automatically as I dont know how deep the param will be. I can assume that deepth will be no more than 10 and for each case write my code like you said but its not so clean solution (if I'll not find anything I will do it this way however)

Comment: How you thought to use recursion? Split the string every time by `.` and the apply the assignment if only there is not a deeper level to go.

Comment: So this string `post.author.title` would assign the value to that property: `post->author['title']` is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to do this. nice little excercise. No idea how to call it, but here you got an example function to do it.

```
class TestClass
{
public $prop2 = "test";
}
class TestClass2
{
    public $prop;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->prop = new TestClass();
    }
}
function deepProperty($obj,$property,$value = null)
{
    $curObj = &$obj;
    $properties = explode('.',$property);
    while(count($properties) > 1)
        $curObj = &$curObj->{array_shift($properties)};
    if ($value != null)
        $curObj->{$properties[0]} = $value;
    return $curObj->{$properties[0]};
}

$object = new TestClass2();

deepProperty($object,"prop.prop2","not test");
echo deepProperty($object,"prop.prop2");
```